# UNION in sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables and I want to display only the child ID that are in the first table and not in the second table. But it gives me always all the ID's, even those that are in the second table. This is the stored procedure;

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[GetAllChildren]

@UserID int

AS

SELECT Child_ID FROM firstTable
UNION
SELECT Child_ID FROM SecondTable WHERE User_ID = @UserID
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[GetAllChildren]
@UserID int
AS
SELECT Child_ID 
FROM firstTable 
WHERE Child_ID NOT IN
      (SELECT Child_ID FROM SecondTable WHERE User_ID = @UserID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using UNION if you dont need second tables child ids

```
SELECT Child_ID FROM firstTable
```

This is enough to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ft.Child_ID
FROM firstTable ft
LEFT JOIN secondTable st
    on ft.Child_ID = st.Child_ID
WHERE st.Child_ID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `UNION` keyword to `EXCEPT` (relational difference a.k.a. minus) e.g.

```
SELECT Child_ID FROM firstTable
EXCEPT
SELECT Child_ID FROM SecondTable WHERE User_ID = @UserID
```